# HTML default fonts

Tags: html, css

I have a website where the fonts of all texts I set to 'Arial Narrow'. Now I tried to view my site on a different computer but the fonts of the texts is in times new roman. I don't know what seems to be the problem, is 'Arial Narrow' font not included in the default web fonts?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Core_fonts_for_the_Web

Comment: how can I do that? I'm sorry I'm new here in SOF.

Comment: You can accept an answer by clicking the green icon below the score of an answer. It will also increase your reputation a little and help others to find what was useful to you.

Comment: thanks for that information. I'll do that.. :-) I am so grateful with all the answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, Arial Narrow is **not** a free font and has to be purchased/licensed if you want to use it on your website. You can purchase it [here](http://www.fonts.com/font/monotype-imaging/arial).

If you would like a list of common web fonts available for free usage, [find out here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Core_fonts_for_the_Web).

Comment: I see. Thanks for the information. I'll just use another font instead.

Comment: can I embed the ttf file in css?

Comment: @clydewinux I know that it was always possible, but never supported in browsers. However, I heard that CSS3 supports it so if you're using that it can most likely be done and supported

Answer (score 0):

No arial is, but arial narrow is not a font family, you will have to change the letter spacing and the font-weight with css, even then I dont know what it would look like in arial without trying it, but its an idea, failing that see my bottom paragraph

eg:

```
.font{
    font-family: "arial";
    letter-spacing:-1px; /* adjust to necessary */
}
```

Try http://www.dafont.com/ or http://www.fontsquirrel.com/ for your font

Comment: Arial Narrow is not light, it’s condensed.

Comment: I see, in that case it would be the letter spacing

Answer (score 0):

Arial Narrow is not a web-safe font. Additionally, I would say for readability, the body text should not be arial narrow. I would recommend either a combination as follows

16pt+ Arial (looks good for headings etc...)
16px- Tahoma (easy to read for body text - and is space efficient)
12px- Vardana (easy to read for very small text)

Or just use `sans-serif` as the font for body text, leaving it up to the user's preference, and use a google web font that matches the style of the site.

n.b. it is also worth remembering that arial is an ugly, crude font that was designed to be a free version of helvetica: http://www.ms-studio.com/articles.html